# Cannot find mistake in PHP + MySQLi register page

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to build a register page using PHP and MySQLi. However, it doesn't work, and I cannot understand the issue. It was previously with no MySQL improved syntax. There is just an empty page in browser.

```
<?php
  include ("bd.php");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  if (isset($_POST['login'])) 
  { 
    $login = $_POST['login']; 
    if ($login == '') 
    { 
      unset($login);
    } 
  }
  if (isset($_POST['password'])) 
  { 
    $password=$_POST['password']; 
    if ($password =='') 
    { 
      unset($password);
    } 
  }
  if (empty($login) or empty($password))
  {
    exit ("You have entered not all of the information, go back and fill in all the fields!");
  }

  $login = stripslashes($login);
  $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
  $password = stripslashes($password);
  $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
  $login = trim($login);
  $password = trim($password);
  $myrow = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'");

  if (!empty($myrow['id'])) 
  {
    exit ("Sorry, you entered login which is already registered . Please enter a different username.");
  }
  $result2=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO users (login,password) VALUES('$login','$password')");
  if ($result2=='TRUE')
  {
    echo "You have successfully signed up!";
  }
  else 
  {
    echo "Failed to sign up";
  }
?>
```

bd.php:

```
<?php  
  $db = new mysqli ("localhost","root","root","kotik");
?>
```

Comment: How doesnt it work? is there an error?

Comment: @NoLiver92 Sorry, I have edited. There is nothing, just white screen, nothing new in database

Comment: add "error_reporting(E_ALL);" to your code and look for errors. Additional you can look in your error log file.

Comment: @Eugen "[23-Jan-2015 19:33:03 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/save_user.php on line 42
 "

Comment: @Eugen line 42 is '  if (!empty($myrow['id'])) '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    include ("bd.php");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}

    $login = isset($_POST['login'] && !empty($_POST['login'])) ? stripslashes(trim($_POST['login'])) : null;
    $password = isset($_POST['login'] && !empty($_POST['login'])) ? stripslashes(trim($_POST['login'])) : null;
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);


    if (empty($login) || empty($password)){exit ("You have entered not all of the information, go back and fill in all the fields!");}


    $res = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'");
    $myrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

    if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {

        exit ("Sorry, you entered login which is already registered . Please enter a different username.");
    }
    $result2 =mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO users (login,password) VALUES('$login','$password')");
    if ($result2 == true)//use true not 'True' because 'True' is a string
    {
        echo "You have successfully signed up!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Failed to sign up";
    }
    ?>
```

EDIT: You should use mysqli_fetch_assoc to get an associative array which corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows.

Comment: still the same result

Comment: You should use something like $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the variable $myrow like this:

```
$myrow['id']
```

You need to get the row then you can treat it like an array. It would look something like this:

```
$row = $myrow->fetch_row()
$row['id']
```

this gets the first row of the results of the query. If the query returns multiple results you can use something like this:

```
while($row = $myrow->fetch_row()) {
  $rows[]=$row;
}
```

Then you use $rows as a normal array and get the individual rows 1 by 1 in a for loop, then you can use the same format:

```
$temp = $rows[0];
$temp['id']
```